# Displaying values from rows into columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have table contains below sample records.

```
select value, FieldID 
from [values] 
where fieldid in (140996, 140997)
```

Output:

```
value Fieldid
--------------
101    140996
102    140996
       140996
Louis  140997
Khan   140997
Akabar 140997
```

I want to display above values from rows into columns like below fieldid is input parameter and Value columns contains any no of rows.

Sample output

```
Fieldid    value1  value2  value3
---------------------------------
140996      101     102       
140997      Louis   Khan   Akabar
```

Comment: You have tagged this with pivot-table so presumably you know about pivot function. Do you have a query that you need assistance in making work?

Comment: Note, you cannot guarantee this `Louis Khan Akabar` values order - there is no column to sort by. So output will randomly put those values into `value1`, `value2`, `value3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use condition aggregate function make pivot.

```
;WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FieldId ORDER BY FieldId) rn
   FROM  [values]
)

SELECT FieldId,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN value END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN value END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN value END)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY FieldId
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0c07d8c2f52c64ec1bb6a97a6923e8d5)

**EDIT**

If you want to let your columns created dynamically.

You can try to use dynamic pivot.

using `CTE` recursion make row number from min row to max row.

then use the row number write  condition aggregate function SQL.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


;WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FieldId ORDER BY FieldId) rn
   FROM  [values]
), CTE2 AS (
   SELECT MIN(rn) minID,MAX(rn) maxID
   FROM CTE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT minID + 1,maxID
   FROM CTE2
   WHERE  minID + 1<=maxID
)

SELECT @cols = @cols + 'MAX(CASE WHEN rn ='+ cast(minID as varchar(5)) +' THEN value END) Value'+CAST(minID AS VARCHAR(5))+','
FROM CTE2

set @cols = substring(@cols,0,len(@cols))


set @query =  '
;WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FieldId ORDER BY FieldId) rn
   FROM  [values]
)
 SELECT FieldId,' + @cols + ' 
 FROM CTE
 GROUP BY FieldId'


execute(@query)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=51b84472c8f7a0fa3be0219f7d0da14c)

Comment: value columns sometimes contains 3 rows or 4 rows or many rows so we cannot predict it.Above query will work when value column contains three rows,suppose it contains many rows,how can we display it?

Comment: You need to use dynamic pivot Wait a second I will write a sample

Comment: yes.it is working.I just added  option (maxrecursion 0) in the query end. SELECT @cols  query.Thanks.

Comment: @Ram Yes if your CTE recursion  data row more than 100 you need to set it:)

Answer (score 0):

You can PIVOT on numbered columns generated via a CONCAT and ROW_NUMBER.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT FieldID, value, 
     CONCAT('value', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FieldId ORDER BY (select 0))) AS col
    FROM [values]
    -- WHERE fieldid IN (140996,140997)
) src
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Value)
    FOR col IN ([value1], [value2], [value3])
) pvt
```

You can test it [here](http://rextester.com/XKGSB77077)

Note that an order by nothing doesn't garantee the same order of the values. So if the table has a primary key then you could order by that instead.